# Facebook iFrame Tab Works For Me But Appears Blank To Everyone Else?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to create a custom tab for a facebook page and it works perfectly for me in firefox and internet explorer 8 in both the tab on the page and as a direct link but for others it just appears blank.

I am also an admin of the page and if I try logging in as someone else then it becomes blank for me too.

Here is my code:

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
try {
    $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/PAGEID");
    if( !empty($likes['data']) )
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fan').click(function() {
                $('#fan').animate({
                    opacity: 0.2,
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 'auto'
                }, 1000, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                    $('#fan').hide('slow');
                    $('#voucher').show('slow');
                });
            });
        });
        </script>

        <a href="#"><img id="fan" src="http://www.website.com/facebook/2011/voucher/fans_image.jpg" alt="10% off" style="border:0;" /></a>
        <div style="display:none; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" id="voucher" >
        <a href="http://www.website.com/facebook/2011/voucher/voucher-11.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.website.com/facebook/2011/voucher/fb-voucher-dec11.jpg" style="border:0;" alt="10% off" /></a>  <br />
        <p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://www.website.com/facebook/2011/voucher/DECEMBER-11.pdf" target="_blank">Click here to download PDF version of the voucher.</a></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <img style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border:0;" id="all" src="http://www.website.com/facebook/2011/voucher/fb_like_page.jpg" width="520" height="304" alt="Click LIKE button to get 10% off" />';
        <?php
    }
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
    }
}

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} 
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_likes'
    ));
}
```

I have developed one other Facebook app in the past that I had similar problems with but that was broke for a few hours and then all of a sudden worked.

I have been fiddling with this all day with the code and the app settings and even changed the permissions of the index.php that is being called in the iframe to 755 but it's still appearing blank :(

**More Info**
The app is *not* in sandbox mode, here are the app settings:

**Basic**

```
Website: Site URL: http://www.website.com/

App on Facebook: Canvas URL: http://www.website.com/facebook/2011/discount-voucher/
               : Secure Canvas URL: https://www.website.com/facebook/2011/discount-voucher/

Page Tab: Page Tab URL: index.php
          Secure Page Tab URL: index.php
```

**Advanced**

```
 App Type: Web
 Deauthorize Callback: *blank*
 Sandbox Mode: Disabled

Migrations:
Remove Deprecated APIs: Enabled
Stream post URL security: Disabled
Timezone-less events: Enabled
Upgrade to Requests 2.0: Enabled
Require manage_notifications: Enabled
Include recent activity stories: Enabled
Enhanced Auth Dialog: Enabled
page_hours_format: Enabled
Graph Batch API Exception Format: Enabled
```

Comment: is your application in sandbox mode?

Comment: Hi Lix, sorry that's one thing I forgot to add - it's *not* in sandbox mode. Also, I just checked IE8 again, direct link is now blank for me but the tab still works. :/

Comment: I can but I am a little scared to! http://www.facebook.com/opticalexpress?sk=app_325932007433280 is the tab, direct link is www.opticalexpress.com/facebook/2011/discount-voucher/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `Page Tab URL` and `Secure Page Tab URL` to reflect actual, **absolute** URL's.

Comment: I'm sure I tried that before but will try it again now - whilst I was doing my research a website (can't remember which one) said that this was just the file name and that the absolute part should only go in the canvas url fields. (Just to let you know why I did that in the first place.)

Comment: I'm almost sure that this is your problem.  The little "?" next to the Page Tab URL field calls it a "Base URL".

Comment: ok, thanks. As far as I can tell it's still blank for others, if you are able to do a couple of refreshes over the next few minutes I would really appreciate it.

Comment: just tried it in Chrome as a different user, still blank I'm afraid. If I right click and go to view frame source it just comes back as blank!

Comment: Hmm, just logged in as me on Chrome and it works. Therefore I can only assume it genuinely only works for me and noone else!

Comment: this was part of the problem but the main thing was an ssl certificate for over https.

Comment: ahh -yes... that may be the **most** important stage :P